# Why git pull is not pulling the newly created branch that was pushed to remote?

Tags: git, git-pull

I thought `git pull`  = `git fetch` + `git merge`

This is good for sometime to pull the changes in remote branches, until encountering a situation where in `git pull` is not pulling the newly created branch. By newly created branch, what I meant is that "someone else"
just created a new branch and pushed to remote, and I tried to do a `git pull`, but I am not getting the new branch onto my list of remote branches.

I was able to get this newly created branch only after I did a `git fetch` and then `git merge`.

**Question:**
So does this mean, always do a `git pull` only when you want to pull changes of an existing branch,
and do a `git fetch` + `git merge` when you want to pull a newly created branch?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @uDaY . Now I understand how to do this in *git bash*. But wondering if we want to do this from Eclipse IDE, how can we make aware to Eclipse git pull utility to execute a `git pull -all` instead of the default `git pull`? Any thoughts?

Update1 : Ignore it, I will post as new question.

**Update2: 09/23/2015** Well, Another question is not needed, I figured it out. Here it is,

> Pull is basically fetch + merge

So unless you define what fetch has to really fetch, you cant expect a pull to pull what you intend to pull!

What this means is , In eclipse Since you cannot configure a `pull`, you must have to configure '`Fetch`'.
ie: Right click on

> project->Team->Remote->Configure Fetch from Upstream

.
See if some mapping is defined under '*refmappings*'. Whatever, go to *Advanced*, and a new window will popup
which says '*Configure Fetch*' - Fetch Ref Specifications-Select refs to fetch
Make sure you have Source Ref as "refs/heads/*"  and Destination Ref as "refs/remotes/origin/*" , and Force Update checkbox as checked.

I also did one extra step, by selecting the dropdown for '*Source ref:*' and picked up the new branch name eg: `newbranch`, 
selecting the dropdown for '*Destination ref:*' and picked up the new branch name eg: `origin/newbranch`, and clicked on "*+ Add Spec*",
and click on "*Finish*". Now *Save* it.

Finally do a *pull*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git pull by default doesn't fetch all the branches. If you want to pull all the branches using git pull you need to do

`$ git pull --all`

see the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> `git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`
>
> Default values for `<repository>` and `<branch>` are read from the
>   "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by
>   git-branch[1] --track.